# Is there a counterpart to the VirtualBox command 'vboximg-mount' on macOS? (i.e., How do I unmount?)

Tags: virtualbox

I can find official documentation on [FUSE-mounting virtual disk images](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97728_01/E97727/html/vboximg-mount.html) but there doesn't seem to be a way to unmount.

Does anybody know how I can unmount a FUSE-mounted filesystem on the specified virtual disk image?

Comment: I was able to use "umount" to unmount the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
fusermount -u yourmountpoint
```

See fusermount -h